# Querying in DynamoDb without key condition expression

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

I am new in DynamoDb but I want to query data using .NET and I am I little bit confused that DynamoDb forces me to use Primary key and KeyConditionExpression.

For example in SQL I can do something like this `SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE name = 'Alex'` and in this case name is **NOT** a primary key. But I can not do something similar in DynamoDb.

Here is my code:

```
        var request = new QueryRequest
        {
            TableName = "CompanyCommunication",
            KeyConditionExpression = "Id = :v_Id",
            FilterExpression = "CompanyName = :v_Com",
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
            {":v_Com", new AttributeValue { S =  "Microsoft" }} , {":v_Id", new AttributeValue { S = "1" }  }  }
        };
```

Id is my primary key. But I can not comment KeyConditionExpression or use some another field in KeyConditionExpression.

But how I can do a query **not using primary key**? 
For example, using only a CompanyName field.

Maybe I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query without putting KeyCondition then you have to have Index table. You can check following link for more details.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

It explains with examples to use GSI.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramdev Sharma, I will look at it.